# How to obtain total number of views for a user combining questions and answers?

Tags: discussion, data-explorer, views

I'm interested in how to communicate the  value of a contribution to StackExchange sites to others who know nothing about StackExchange. I thought that one index would be to have a total view count of questions and answers that a user has contributed to.

I've had a look around https://data.stackexchange.com/ but I couldn't find anything that does that.

Thus, my question:

**Is there any way to extract the total number of  views a set of questions has received, where that set is defined as those that a user has either contributed an answer or the question?**

Comment: This would definitely be possible, all questions track their view counts over in the sidebar. So it would just be a matter of writing a query to extract this information. For that, you'll need someone who knows SQL, someone other than me! Otherwise, you'll have to add them up by hand.

Comment: It is good to know that it is possible. I'll see if I can tweak an existing one.

Answer (score 1):

[View count per user](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/201459/viewcount-per-user) would be the query that answers your question.

```
select top 1000 u.id as [User Link]
, sum(ViewCount) as [Total Views]
from Posts p 
inner join users u on u.id = p.owneruserid
group by u.id
order by [Total Views] desc
```